# ASP.NET Core Web API : registration of controllers in StartUp

Tags: controller, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there any possibility to register controllers in StartUp?

For example I know that `FooService` will send a `POST` request to the URI `/foo`. I do not want to create controller which will resolve this request (this controller will be written in other program).

I would like to register this controller using extension method.

For example:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // ...
    app.UseFooController();

    // ...
}
```

Is there any possibilities to add controllers using this path in an ASP.NET Core Web API?

Comment: Why not use the built in AddControllers?

Comment: You mean AddControllers extension method for IServiceCollection?

Answer (score 0):

I just used AddControllers and then in Use endpoints i registered my controllers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).